# How to add Lottie Animation in Phaser3?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, phaser-framework, lottie

> I am trying to add Lottie animation in the Phaser 3 in my game.

But I am not able to add. Here problem is, this animation I am attaching to the HTML DOM elements and so that the animation comes above the Phaser game canvas, Due to what I am not able to interact with my phaser game elements. I am not able to include the Lottie animation JSON file inside my Phaser game canvas.

I have also tried to make container to be the canvas, but it is not working.

Here is the example of the Lottie animation used in HTML5: [Lottie animation Demo](https://codepen.io/MarioD/pen/dybGJaB?&page=1)

This is the link to the Lottie animation file:
[Lottie animation JSON file example](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/49240/stick-man.json)

Here is the code I am using for this,

```
 this.animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById("game"), // Required
      path: "assets/json/RainLoop.json", // Required
      renderer: "canvas", // Required
      loop: true, // Optional
      autoplay: true, // Optional
      name: "Hello World", // Name for future reference. Optional.
    });
```

I want to include this Lottie animation to be include inside Phaser game canvas, but it is only including to my HTML DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible there is not yet a supported way to load Lottie animations into a Phaser game canvas. Phaser can only display objects in the game canvas that are brought in with a loader, like `this.load.sprite()`, in the `preload()` method.

Unfortunately, it looks like the structure of Lottie json files doesn't match with the [expected format](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Animations.html#.JSONAnimation) -- [[example]](https://www.foysalahamed.com/blog/learning/phaser-3-animation-using-local-json-file/) -- for the `this.load.animation()` loader.

You could attempt to parse the Lottie `JSON` file into the appropriate format, but that's probably going to be very complicated.

If you want to use your Lottie animation as a background, you could set the Phaser canvas to transparent in the config object like this:

```
var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  transparent: true,
  ...
};
```

And then you can load the Lottie animation into your HTML positioned appropriately with CSS to sit behind your canvas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @brae. I have already tried putting Lottie animation behind the canvas and it is working, But when I put background image for the canvas phaser game, I am not able to see the Lottie animation, as bg image will cover that.

Comment: Is the background image staying fixed in your canvas? Or is it scrolling with player movement?

Comment: I fixed this issue. I kept my bg in a div keeping the z-index of the bg div to -10, above that I kept Lottie div. Also made my phaser canvas transparent. It worked for now.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. You might consider opening a feature request for Lottie animation support for future releases of Phaser.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Sure I am going to do that.